# How to convert deprecated jquery bind() to proper jquery on()

Tags: jquery

I am updating my codebase to latest version of jquery and I am changing my code so all deprecated code is removed. I am not sure how to change the following code I came upon. I know jquery bind is deprecated and I know it's recommended to use on instead. For example, `$(".elem").bind("click", function(){})` can easily be converted to `$(".elem").on("click", function(){})`. However, I am not sure how I could convert the following code.

```
{
    name: "id",
    style: "word-wrap:break-word;width:10%",
    title: this.$globalizer.delete,
    classes: "text-center ",
    filterable: false,
    sortable: false,
    formatter: this.formatDeleteButton.bind(this)
}
```

I am referring to the last line of code, `formatter:this.formatDeleteButton.bind(this)`

Comment: That is not jQuery bind. That is [Function.protoype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Ahh so this is perfectly fine to leave as is then correct?

Comment: would affect whatever that function does if you changed it